# Python writing to port with arduino

Tags: python, arduino, pycharm

I'm trying to send a python script to my Arduino Nano, but it only works when in IDLE. I'm only starting to learn python so my understanding is limited on how to execute scripts.

Here's the python script

```
import serial
ser1 = serial.Serial('COM5', 9600)
ser1.write('s'.encode())
```

I already have pyscript installed. When I type in the above code one line at a time in IDLE, CMD or PowerShell it works flawlessly. when I try to make it a file in pycharm I get the error "No module named 'serial'"

Here's my Arduino code

```
void setup() {
   pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
   digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, 
   Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if(Serial.available() > 0)
  {
    if(Serial.read() == 's')
    {
      digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN,HIGH);
      delay(2000);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PyCharm like to have you configure a separate virtual enviroment for each python project. You can either redo "pip install pyserial --user" inside PyCharm or fiddle with the project settings.